# Can't repartiton disk after scientific Linux (stubborn LVM)

Tags: arch-linux, partition, system-installation, lvm, scientific-linux

I'm distro hopping from scientific Linux, but can't free any disk space.

```
root@archiso~# lsblk
NAME          TYPE
sda           disk      
|-sda1        part 
|-sda2        part
  |-sl-swap   lvm
  |-sl-home   lvm
  |-sl-root   lvm
```

I've tried to reformat sda (dd, gparted ect) to no avail. I've also tried to use lvm tools to remove the volumes, no luck, The volumes don't seem to exist!

```
root@archiso~# lvs -v
  No volume groups found.

root@archiso~# vgscan -v
  No volume groups found.

root@archiso~# lvmdiskscan
...
1 disk
5 partitions
0 lvm physical volume whole disks
0 lvm physical volumes


root@archiso~# lvscan -v
  No volume groups found.

root@archiso~# pvscan
  No matching physical volumes found

root@archiso~# ls /dev/mapper
control sl-home sl-root sl-swap
```

what on earth is going on?

Comment: lsblk might show outdated data after you messed up the partition table. do a reboot or a partscan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with

```
cd /dev
rm -rf mapper/*
rm -rf dm-0 dm-1 dm-2
```

Then `dd`'d `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda` for good measure